# MPI error with large number of process

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have a simple MPI program, everything is fine for a small number of processes = {10,100, and 1000}, the problem is that for 10000 processes I have a runtime error.

I tested my code on 4 nodes cluster within grid5000 platform (on each node: 2 CPUs Intel Xeon E5-2630 v3, 8 cores/CPU, 126GB RAM, 5x558GB HDD, 186GB SSD, 10Gbps ethernet)
The mpi.c file contains the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int myRank, numProcs;
 MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);

if(myRank==0) printf("%d -%d\n",numProcs,myRank);

MPI_Finalize();
return(0);
}
```

The following text is an extract from the message error  for n = 10 000:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device.
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr][[53314,1],3876][../../../../../../ompi/mca/btl/openib/btl_openib_component.c:1504:init_one_device] error obtaining device context for mlx4_0 errno says Cannot allocate memory
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr][[53314,1],348][../../../../../../ompi/mca/btl/openib/btl_openib_component.c:1504:init_one_device] error obtaining device context for mlx4_0 errno says Cannot allocate memory
.
CMA: unable to open RDMA device
CMA: unable to open RDMA device
CMA: unable to open RDMA device
CMA: unable to open RDMA device
.
.
[grimoire-8.nancy.grid5000.fr][[53314,1],9995][../../../../../../ompi/mca/btl/openib/btl_openib_component.c:1504:init_one_device] error obtaining device context for mlx4_0 errno says Cannot allocate memory
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:17190] 1209 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-btl-openib.txt / error in device init
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
At least one pair of MPI processes are unable to reach each other for
MPI communications.  This means that no Open MPI device has indicated
that it can be used to communicate between these processes.  This is
an error; Open MPI requires that all MPI processes be able to reach
each other.  This error can sometimes be the result of forgetting to
specify the "self" BTL.

  Process 1 ([[53314,1],1560]) is on host: grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr
  Process 2 ([[53314,1],1]) is on host: grimoire-4
  BTLs attempted: openib self sm

Your MPI job is now going to abort; sorry.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  PML add procs failed
  --> Returned "Unreachable" (-12) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** The MPI_Init() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:17584] Abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1560 with PID 17584 on
node grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr exiting without calling "finalize". This may
have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** The MPI_Init() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:17999] Abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
.
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:18802] Abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:17190] 23 more processes have sent help message help-mca-bml-r2.txt / unreachable proc
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:17190] 5 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-runtime / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
[grimoire-1.nancy.grid5000.fr:17190] 18 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-runtime / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like 10,000 processes is too much, even for a 128 GB cluster node. If you are 100% sure this is not the cause, please edit your question to explain what makes you think so.

Comment: Anyway, why so many processes? They will be competing like crazy for CPU time. Unless you have enough CPUs to a few thousand threads without  too many of them competing for CPU time, I find it hard to justify such architecture.

Comment: You are asking the OS to execute 2500 processes on a node with 126 GB available RAM. That makes 52 MB per process. Given the amount of private memory a typical MPI library reserves, this is simply not going to work. Not to mention that you are probably also hitting certain OS limits. Did you already get angry phone calls from the system administrators? :)

Comment: In fact, I have some test to do on matrices where I need a number of processes equal to the dimension of my matrix. To check that the problem was not because of my code, I re-tested with this simple code on 10000 process but i get the same error.

Comment: It works with a number of processes up to 1784. from 1785 process I get the same error. Is there a way to know how many MPI processes can we have?